# Why are my different instance variables linking together despite the .copy()?

Tags: python, instance, global

as a novice to python, I feel like it's a lot to ask random strangers what the problem is for every measly problem but after researching, I cannot find out the problem.
What I created was a 2D grid movement system using lists in a list. The end goal was for the user to walk continuously through corridors but after the first corridor, a present would continuously appear in a set location. However, the first time the user walks over the present, the present is deleted from the hardcoded art (lobby_art) that is only connected to the list that is edited (currentlocation).
Below is an attempt to excavate the problem out from the code and simplify it.

```
lobby_art = [
    ['‖ ', '  ', '  ‖'],
    ['‖ ', '', '  ‖'],
    ['‖ ', '  ', '  ‖'],
    ['‖ ', '', '  ‖'],
]

currentlocation = [
    ['‖ ', '  ', '  ‖'],
    ['‖ ', '  ', '  ‖'],
    ['‖ ', '  ', '  ‖'],
    ['‖ ', '', '  ‖'],
]

def moveup(direction):
    if direction == 'w':
        global currentlocation
        global userlocationY
        if userlocationY == 0:
            global leave_corridor 
            leave_corridor = False
            currentlocation[userlocationY][1] = '  ' #deletes previous location
            return
        currentlocation[userlocationY][1] = '  ' 

        userlocationY -= 1
        currentlocation[userlocationY][1] = ''

def lobbyprint(): #Prints Lobby layout
    global currentlocation
    for i in currentlocation: 
        print(''.join(i))

Corridor_with_present = False
GameOngoing = True  
while GameOngoing:        
    
    
    if Corridor_with_present == True:
        currentlocation = lobby_art.copy()
    
    leave_corridor = True
    userlocationY = 3
    while leave_corridor:
        lobbyprint()
        direction = input("Input w: ")
        moveup(direction)

    Corridor_with_present = True
```

Output

```
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
‖   ‖
Input w: w
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
‖   ‖
‖     ‖
Input w: w
‖     ‖
‖   ‖
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
Input w: w
‖   ‖
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
Input w: w
‖     ‖
‖   ‖
‖     ‖
‖   ‖
Input w: w
‖     ‖
‖   ‖
‖   ‖
‖     ‖
Input w: w
‖     ‖
‖   ‖
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
Input w: w
‖   ‖
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
Input w: w
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
Input w: w
‖     ‖
‖     ‖
‖   ‖
‖     ‖
Input w:
```

I have tried using .copy(), [:], even import copy on the statement but to no avail.

```
if Corridor_with_present == True:
        currentlocation = lobby_art.copy()
```

Does anyone know why?

Thanks Robert.

Comment: You might need https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly is related, but discusses list multiplication rather than `copy`. The same lessons apply, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import copy
if Corridor_with_present == True:
        currentlocation = copy.deepcopy(lobby_art)
```

lobby_art.copy() just copy the reference, while `copy.deepcopy(lobby_art)` copy the whole object in memory.

just like the image shown below:
[image]